# method in Report Builder custom assembly not found

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I'm trying to use a custom assembly in Report Builder 2.0.  I have added the assembly to the report via Report Properties > References.  When I try to call a public static method in the assembly, I get this message:

> 'ExtractTag' is not a member of 'ReportsClassLibrary.ReportsClassLibraryTools'.

The expression I'm trying to use to call the method is:

```
=ReportsClassLibrary.ReportsClassLibraryTools.ExtractTag("ID", "ID:incorrect", false)
```

And the method signature in the assembly is:

```
public static string ExtractTag(string tagToFind, string tags, bool caseSensitive)
```

That method is within the `ReportsClassLibrary` namespace and in the `ReportsClassLibraryTools` class.

I don't know if for some reason my report is looking an older version of the assembly that did not have this method, or if the problem is something else.  I've tried removing the assembly from the report, rebuilding the assembly, and re-adding it to the report.

**Edit:** looks like a deeper problem.  My assembly compiles, but when running a test case that calls that method, the test fails with a System.MissingMethodException.  Guess I'm having an assembly problem, not a Report Builder problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was a problem with the Global Assembly Cache in Vista.  The old version of my assembly was cached, so the new method `ExtractTag` wasn't part of the assembly.  I had to run:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\gacutil.exe" /i bin\Debug\ReportsClassLibrary.dll
```